# variables not being compared right

Tags: c++, if-statement, linked-list, insertion-sort

Below is the class I have written to generate sorted linked list in C++
the exact same code worked when it was not template.
However, once I have templated, the code seems to not compare the variables correctly.

For instance,
When I inserted 1, -1, 13
The list should have -1 1 13 in increasing order.
However, the final list came out to be 13 -1 1.

During debugging, it did not even go through the last case.
It when into the second case, saying that 13 was less than -1.

What is going on ...?

```
template <class ItemType>
bool List342<ItemType>::Insert(ItemType *obj)
{
Node *insNode = new Node;
insNode->data = obj;

if (head == NULL)
{
    head = insNode;
    return true;
}

if (obj <= head->data)
{
    insNode->next = head;
    head = insNode;
    return true;
}

Node *pNode = head;
while ((pNode->next != NULL) && ((pNode->next)->data <= obj))
{
    pNode = pNode->next;
}
insNode->next = pNode->next;
pNode->next = insNode;
return true;
}
```

here is the node definition

```
struct Node {
    ItemType *data;
    Node *next;
};
```

Comment: What did you watch, when stepping through your code line by line with a debugger?

Comment: it was doing good until the insertion of 1 and -1. but when it got to the insertion of 13, it simply went into the case where obj <= head -> data. the value was shown as -1 and 13 though.... thus inserting 13 before -1.

Comment: Can we see the definition of Node?

Comment: Actually... The function is receiving "ItemType *obj" as it's parameter. It's receiving a pointer to an ItemType, not an ItemType. Thus "obj <= head->data" compares the memory locations, not the values they contain.

Comment: I see... thanks. I am still struggling with the concept of pointer... :(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparisons `(obj <= head->data)` and `((pNode->next)->data <= obj)` are apparently between `ItemType *` pointers. If you want to compare between the `ItemType` objects they point to instead, you need to dereference the pointers. For example, test  `(*obj <= *head->data)`.

Comment: This worked!, so when comparing to a pointer, both values need to be pointer value..?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: So, when I took obj as parameter, it was accepted as *obj, pointer. and pNode is also declared as a pointer. Then, when I tried to use them later, do I need to specify that they are pointer again? shouldn't (obj <= head->data) be same as (*obj <= *head->data)

Comment: That's not quite right. Once the name `obj` has been declared as a variable of type `ItemType *`, every subsequent usage of `obj` refers to that pointer variable. On the other hand, `*obj` refers to the object that `obj` points to. The asterisk `*` is the dereferencing operator; it doesn't merely re-express that `obj` is a pointer. (You might be confused if you're trying to compare with languages like Perl that use typed sigils. In C++, there are no sigils.) Numerically, `obj` might equal an address like 0x5f790ea2, whereas `*obj` might equal 13.